# what's the difference of the two list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I'm a newbie to scheme. I'm just confused about the difference of the following two list.

```
(define a '(1 2))
(define a '(1 . 2))
```

I think a equal to b, but

```
(equal? a b)
```

return #f to me.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two aren't the same. The first is a normal list. In dotted notation it would look like this:

```
(1 . (2 . nil))
```

A normal list stores data in the `car` of a `cons` cell, and the `cdr` is only used to store a pointer to the next `cons` cell in the list, or Nil for the last cell in the list.

Your definition of `a` uses only one `cons` cell, with `1` in the `car` and `2` in the `cdr`.

If you drew them out graphically, they'd look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "dot" notation is used in Scheme and LISP to describe "improper lists", those that don't follow the standard list data definition.  This question:

[Functional Programming: what is an "improper list"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919097/functional-programming-what-is-an-improper-list/1919239#1919239)

... probably answers most of your questions.  Let me know if there's anything this post doesn't answer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I just have known another concept of fp.

Answer (score 0):

They don't return equal because they are not the same data type. the first one with: `(define a '(1 . 2))` is what is known as a pair. A list is a pair but not all pairs are lists. Lists are pairs that have a `car` and their `cdr` is a list. When you get the dot notation it means that the `car` of that pair is 1 and the `cdr` is 2. Since they aren't the same data type, they can't be equal.