# what is the syntax [33|44]?

Tags: erlang

This is what I do in my Erlang shell:

```
Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [smp:2:2] [rq:2]
    [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
1> A = [33|44].
[33|44]
2> is_list(A).
true
5> length(A).
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  length/1
    called as length([33|44])
```

What is this object [33|44] ? Is it really a list ?

Comment: It's an "improper list".  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922724/113848) explains it well.

Comment: Quick search for "[erlang pipe operator](https://www.google.com/search?q=erlang+pipe+operator)": http://www.evanmiller.org/joy-of-erlang.html#section3