# Erlang pattern matching error

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I have started learning Erlang recently and came across the following error while trying to pattren match

The following expression is working fine:

```
{A,_,[B|_],{B}}={abc,23,[22,x],{22}}.
Resulting in
A = abc
B = 22
```

The following expression is not working:

```
{A,_,[_|B],{B}}={abc,23,[22,x],{x}}.
Is resulting in 
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {abc,23,[22,x],{x}}
```

However if I replace the ',' in [22 , x with a | like the following its working find and bounding x to B

```
{A,_,[_|B],{B}}={abc,23,[22|x],{x}}.
{abc,23,[22|x],{x}}
B.
x
```

Any explanation about this would highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: [_|Whatever] can mean literally *anything*, so it can't be matched, because `_` can consume/match anything, including the entire element of the match. That means "Anything at all, followed by `Whatever` -- which we don't define here". `[22|Whatever]` or any `[FiniteThing|_]` means "something concrete and limited, followed by `Whatever`", which can be matched because it can match and consume the first part of the list exactly. IOW, "anything" matches/consumes *everything*, whereas a specific and limited thing can only represent itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `|` is used for a recursive definition of a list: `[A|B]` means that you add the element `A` to an existing list `B`. `A` is the first element of the resulting list, called the head, `B` is the rest of the list called tail. `B` can be also split into a head and a tail, and the process can continue until the tail is equal to the empty list `[]`.

The operator , is a separator between list elements, so `[A,B]` is a list of 2 elements `A` and `B`.

The 2 operators can be combined: `[A,B,C|D]` is a list of at least 3 elements, which are `A`, `B` and `C`, and a tail `D` which can be empty.

In your test you used another syntax: `[23|x]`; 23 can be an element of a list (in fact any erlang term can be an element of a list) but x is an atom and cannot be a list tail. Doing this you broke the recursive definition of the list, this structure is not often used and is called an improper list.

- when you match `[_|B]` and `[_,x]`, you assign `[x]` to `B` which do not match to `x` later in the expression
- when you match `[_|B]` and `[_|x]`, you assign `x` to `B` which indeed match to `x` later in the expression, but the right way should be
- `{A,_,[_|B],{B}}={abc,23,[22,x],{[x]}}.`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explaination

Answer (score 1):

You need to look closer on how does the `|` operator works. It basically takes head of list, which is one element, and returns tail of list, which is all the rest.  And like "all" suggest tail is also a list.  It could be one element list, it could be even empty list, but still it's gonna be a list.

```
> [Head| Tail] = [23,x].
[23,x]
> Head.
23
> Tail
[x].
```

So in your pattern matching, you assign to be tail `[x]`, and than try to pattern match on simply `x`.  And that's what's failing.

On side note: you can create new list with `|` operator, but you should do this with caution. since you could create [improper list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919097/functional-programming-what-is-an-improper-list) (and you do with `[23 | x]`). That's why your "fix" is working.

If you would like to match on two element list, you could do it explicitly with

```
[A, B] =  [23, x].
```

but this will fail if list have more or less elements.

If you would like to match on only on two first elements, you can still use `|` operator.

```
> [A, B | Rest] = [23, x].
[23, x]
> A.
23
> B.
x
> Rest.
[].
```

And this will fail only with one-element or empty list.