# Checking of list of symbols has the dot symbol?

Tags: scheme

I have a list of the form `'(x y . rest)` (of the form of lambda with optional number of arguments).
I need to check whether I have such a case, but I seem to fail to check that. What I was planning to do is search if `.` is a member of the list.

```
> (memq '\. '(x y z . rest))
Exception in memq: improper list (x y z . rest)
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.

> (memq . '(x y z . rest))
Exception: invalid syntax (x y z . rest)
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.

> (memv '\. '(x y z \. rest))
(\x2E; rest) ;this worked but my input is of the form '(x y z . rest) and not '(x y z \. rest)
```

Comment: Have a look at *improper lists* in [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#ImproperLists).

Comment: Have a look at [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433).  What you actually need to look for is whether the last `cdr` in the chain is the empty list or something else.

Comment: While we're talking about SRFI 1, it provides a `dotted-list?` predicate that seems like exactly what the OP is seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `(x y z . rest)` does *not* have a dot symbol in it. It's actually an improper list, made this way: `(cons 'x (cons 'y (cons 'z 'rest)))`.

To test for an improper list, you can do something like this:

```
(define (improper-list? x)
  (cond ((null? x) #f)
        ((pair? x) (improper-list? (cdr x)))
        (else #t)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.` symbol is not part of the list, it's just a convention to print an [improper list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1919629/201359) (one that does not end in an empty list). To test if we have an improper list, try this using built-in procedures:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))

(define (improper-list? lst)
  (or (atom? lst)
      (not (list? lst))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(improper-list? 1)
=> #t
(improper-list? '())
=> #f
(improper-list? '(1 2 3))
=> #f
(improper-list? '(1 2 . x))
=> #t
```

Comment: I like my definition better, since it aligns with the SRFI 1 definition of an improper list, which also counts standalone atoms (which are improper lists of length 0).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Ok, got it. I believe it's fixed now :P

Comment: Uh, I think `(improper-list? 1)` should be true. If you think inductively, it will make sense: an improper list is: 1. an atom that isn't an empty list, or 2. a pair where the cdr points to an improper list. This also makes sense when you think of the lambda syntax for declaring a function that takes 1+ arguments, vs one that takes 0+ arguments.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Mmm, I misunderstood the definition then :( . _Now_ it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no **.** element in your list.  Rather, it's a notation that's used when the last cdr in a list is not the empty list.   That's been described in other questions, too, though.  For instance, have a look at [Dot notation in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433).

As to checking for improper lists, the other two answers are correct, and take similar approaches.  However, I think specifying a *proper list* is a bit cleaner, and that it makes for a nicer definition to define **proper-list?** and then define **improper-list?** in terms of it:

```
(define (proper-list? x)
  ;; a proper list is either the empty list (), or a pair
  ;; whose cdr is a proper list.
  (or (null? x)
      (and (pair? x)
           (proper-list? (cdr x)))))

(define (improper-list? x)
  ;; an improper list is anything that is not a proper list
  (not (proper-list? x)))
```