# What means the pipe character found in the inspection string of an Elixir list?

Tags: elixir

I have the following Elixir script:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [a | 3]
IO.puts is_list(b)
IO.inspect b
```

I thought that my code `b = [a | 3]` was wrong and this would cause an error.

But when I run this script, I got this result:

```
true
[[1, 2] | 3]
```

What means the pipe character within the last line of output?

Comment: Both answers below are correct, I would just put the answer on “how would I write this code to accomplish a task” here: `b = a ++ [3]`.

Comment: After reading PatNowak's answer, I realized my question was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784320/elixir-list-concatenation. It seems that it is a FAQ on Erlang/Elixir world.

Answer (score 4):

The `|` character is called the `cons` operator and is for linking an elixir term to another elixir term to build linked lists. All "proper" lists end with the empty list like so: `[1 | [2 | [ 3 | []]]]` But you can actually end a list with any elixir term at which point it becomes an "improper" list, like so `[1 | [2 | :three]]]`.

You are seeing that output instead of `[[1,2],3]` because your list is an "improper" list.

This is actually very useful output because in order to pattern match on it you'd have to use the same form. `[[a,b] | c]` would match where as `[[a,b],c]` would not.

Answer (score 2):

The `|` operator splits list into head and tail. 
Head is first element, tail is everything else in another list or just empty list.

Consider this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a = [x | y] # x = 1, y = [2, 3]
hd(a) == x # true
tl(a) == y # true


b = [1]
b = [x | y] # x = 1, y = []
hd(b) # 1
tl(b) # []
```

When you have construct like [1, 3] it means this is [improper list](http://michal.muskala.eu/2015/10/16/understanding-lists.html).

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 3]` `a = [x, y]` gives me a compile error. Maybe you meant `[x | y] = a` as the second statement? Same goes for the latter example.

Comment: Yes, my mistake :)