# erlang; cons operator does not flatten

Tags: erlang

I wrote the function:

```
rotate_bin_list_right([H|T]) ->
  erlang:display(H),
  erlang:display(T),
  erlang:display([T|H]),
  [T|H].
```

When called with `[<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>]`, it prints:

```
 <<"2">>
[<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>]
[[<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>]|<<"2">>]
```

I was expecting a "flattened list":

```
[<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"2">>,<<"3">>,<<"4">>,<<"2">>]
```

What is happening?

Comment: further to what Steve has mentioned in his answer, to get a flattened list as teh return, you must make the 'H' a list, and use the flatten function, like so: `erlang:display(lists:flatten([T|[H]])).`

Comment: @liam_g: It's unnecessarily slow implementation. `lists:flatten/1` is Erlang implemented `++/2` is Bif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for sake of completeness, this is correct implementation:

```
rotate_bin_list_right([H|T]) -> T ++ [H].
```

Comment: I am new to Erlang, and from what I have read, `++` is very bad as opposed to prepending and reversing because it can lead to quadratic recursive functions.

Comment: @Tommy: I see. You are new to Erlang. So take advice from someone who is not. It is the correct implementation of `rotate_list_right/1` if you like this operation. This is not recursive function so it can't lead to any recursive function including quadratic ones.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So is there a way to do this in O(1)?

Comment: @Tommy: No, there is not a way to do it in O(1) but O(N) is good when you consider it is the immutable single-linked list.

Answer (score 3):

`T` is a list and `H` is not a list, so the construct `[T|H]` creates an [improper list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1919097/409228), where the tail is not a list.

Comment: No, @Tommy, `[[H]|T]` gives you a list with a single-element list containing `H` as the head and `T` as the tail.

Comment: @Tommy, see @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil's answer for the correct solution. Your fears of `++` are unfounded, as he explains. Also note that my answer doesn't include a solution because that's not what you asked; you merely asked "what's happening".