# Add new element to list

Tags: elixir

I was trying to add a new element into a list as follow:

```
iex(8)> l = [3,5,7,7,8] ++ 3
[3, 5, 7, 7, 8 | 3]
iex(9)> l
[3, 5, 7, 7, 8 | 3]
```

Why did I get on the 5th position like

```
8 | 3
```

What it does mean?
And how can I add new element to the list?

--------**Update**--------
I try to loop the list as follow:

```
iex(2)> l = [1,2] ++ 3
[1, 2 | 3]
iex(3)> Enum.each(l, fn(x) -> IO.puts(x) end)
1
2
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:604: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"(#Function<6.54118792/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>, 3)
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:604: Enum.each/2
```

Since the pointer of the number 2 is not pointing to a list, rather to value 3, how can I loop the list?

Comment: Google for "Elixir Improper List".  That notation is indicating an improper list.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The ++ operator is for concatenating two lists, then maybe what you want to do in order to add a new element is to put it within a list. Then, I think you should add the *3* into another list:

> iex(2)> l = [3,5,7,7,8] ++ [3]
>
> [3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 3]

Comment: But I want to know what does  `8 | 3`mean?

Comment: Lists in Elixir are linked lists. The A | B means that the pointer of cell A is pointing to B. In your case, it means that the last element of your list is pointing to the element that stores the 3.

Comment: @SalvadorMedina No, in this case the `8 | 3` indicates an improper list.  Google "Elixir improper list" and you'll see what it is.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Oh, thanks for the clarification on the notation! It's great to learn this way.

Comment: a caution from the [docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/List.html#content): "_Due to their cons cell based representation, prepending an element to a list is always fast (constant time), while appending becomes slower as the list grows in size (linear time):_

`iex> list = [1, 2, 3]
iex> [0 | list]   # fast
[0, 1, 2, 3]
iex> list ++ [4]  # slow
[1, 2, 3, 4]`"

Answer (score 94):

Just follow the Elixir docs to add an element to a list ( and keep performance in mind =) ):

```
iex> list = [1, 2, 3]
iex> [0 | list]   # fast
[0, 1, 2, 3]
iex> list ++ [4]  # slow
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html

Comment: Because lists in Elixir / Erlang are linked lists internally, so adding in the front of the list is a fast operation because you don't need to recreate the links on the tail of the list. So adding the element in the end of the list will require the linked list to recreate all links again from back to front.

Comment: I didn't understand how appending an element to a linked list could be computationally expensive while prepending was cheap until I saw this snippet, which shows cons cells underlying the List:
`iex> [1 | [2 | [3 | []]]]
[1, 2, 3]
`

Comment: @EduardoPereira In essence it is correct, though the links are not recreated, they are traversed. Traversing is a read operation. Adding an element at the head only requires the added element to contain the link to the rest of the list (tail). Adding at the end requires the end to be found first, meaning the whole list needs to be traversed, and then the last element is updated to contain the link to the added element. It is the traversing that introduces the performance impact, which is in line with what you said.

Answer (score 10):

First: [1, 2 | 3] is the notation for an [improper list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919097/functional-programming-what-is-an-improper-list).

Second: To do the Enum.each you're trying to do with an improper list the code would look like this:

> Matching against proper/improper lists is correspondingly easy. So a
>   length function len for proper lists:
>
> len([_|T]) -> 1 + len(T); len([]) -> 0. where we explicitly match for
>   the terminating []. If given an improper list this will generate an
>   error. While the function last_tail which returns the last tail of a
>   list can handle improper lists as well:
>
> last_tail([_|T]) -> last_tail(T); last_tail(Tail) -> Tail.
>   %Will match any tail

That is, of course, [Erlang code from @rvirding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922724/2820). Translated to Elixir and translated to do the printing you give in your example, it'd look like this:

```
iex(6)> defmodule T do
...(6)>   defp print([h|t]) do
...(6)>     IO.puts(h)
...(6)>     print(t)
...(6)>   end
...(6)>   defp print(t) do
...(6)>     IO.puts(t)
...(6)>   end
...(6)>   def print_improper_list(il), do: print(il)
...(6)> end
iex:6: warning: redefining module T
{:module, T,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 5, 136, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68, 99, 0, 0, 0, 161, 131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100, 111, 99, 115, 95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 2, ...>>,
 {:print_improper_list, 1}}
iex(7)> T.print_improper_list([1,2,3|4])
1
2
3
4
:ok
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to do that with an Enum.each.

Answer (score 9):

Join by [Enum.concat](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#concat/2)

**Example:**

```
iex> new_elem = 5
iex> Enum.concat([1, 2, 3], [new_elem])
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: It uses `Kernel.++/2` internally for concatenating lists.

Answer (score -5):

The "I" means that the list is divided into head and tail like so [head | tail]. If you pattern match the list this way you can manipulate both parts of the list and use the ++ operator for concatenation.