# Elixir List Syntax error

Tags: elixir

I am struggling with Elixir's List, Tuple, Keyword List etc.  Whats wrong with this list?

This works

```
iex> [1, one: "one"] #=> [1, {:one, "one"}]
```

But this doesnt

```
iex> [one: "one", 1] #=> Syntax error before 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how the Elixir syntax is [defined in the parser](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/74825645e8cac770708f45139e651fd9d4e4264c/lib/elixir/src/elixir_parser.yrl#L529-L535): the `identifier : expr` syntax (corresponds roughly to the `kw` rule in the parser linked before) is only accepted at the end of a list literal.

Comment: @Bala to archive want you wanna try in your second example, you can use `++` operator: `iex(11)> [one: "one"] ++ [1] #=> [{:one, "one"}, 1]` or directly write your tuple with the correct syntax `{:one, "one"}`. Mixing up different "magic" syntax spellings makes it difficult for any parser to guess what you really want ;-)

Comment: BTW: In this context it might also be advisable to look at the topic "Improper lists" => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919097/functional-programming-what-is-an-improper-list